# Are there Table Literals in Transact-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

According to http://www.storytotell.org/blog/2008/11/14/literal-tables-and-updates-with-joins-in-sql.html

the following is valid:

```
SELECT * 
        FROM VALUES 
        ('Lisp', 50, true), 
        ('Scheme', 30, true), 
        ('Clojure', 1, true) 
        AS languages (name, age, lispy)
```

But it doesn't appear to work.

The best i can get is

```
With languages (name, age, lispy) as
(
    select 'Lisp', 50, 'true' union all 
    select 'Scheme', 30, 'true' union all 
    select 'Clojure', 1, 'true'
)
select * from languages
```

which uses a common table expression and is not quite as neat.

Is there anything like a table literal in t-sql?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2008, you can use it anywhere a derived table is allowed, although it only lets you have up to 1000 rows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382(SQL.100).aspx

Here's an example from the documentation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634(SQL.100).aspx ):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    VALUES (1, 2),
           (3, 4),
           (5, 6),
           (7, 8),
           (9, 10)
) AS MyTable(a, b)
```

Note the parentheses around the `VALUES` clause.

Comment: +1: I have to wonder why someone would bother, when a UNION'd subquery does the same.

Comment: OMG Ponies: You can have 1000 rows in a table value constructor. I doubt you can union that many rows together in a single query.

Comment: For the same reason someone would bother, when 5 copy pasted individual queries would do the same.

It turns out what I was missing was the placement of the parenthesis. Thank you Gabe.

Comment: how can i use this literal table form on the right side of a join? i can't seem to get the syntax right

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `SELECT * FROM VALUES ...` is standard SQL, however, it is not supported by Microsoft's T-SQL. T-SQL, to my knowledge, only supports `VALUES ...` in `INSERT` statements. (And even then, only supported multiple values as of SQL Server 2008...)

You can see the grammar of a `SELECT` statement's `FROM` clause here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx