# How to join two literal tables together in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3508413/543873) it is shown how a literal table can be created.  However, I want to perform a full outer join or inner join on two literal tables, but I cannot figure out the syntax of the literal table after the join.

I have tried several variations on this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(VALUES (1), (3), (5), (7), (9) ) AS X(a)
JOIN 
(VALUES (0), (2), (4), (6), (8) ) AS Y(b);
```

I get the error:

```
SQL Error (102): Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I have tried removing the outer parentheses around the second literal table:

```
SQL Error (156): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.
```

I tried with and without the AS statements, and also tried removing other parentheses wherever I could think of.

What is the correct syntax to join two literal tables in T-SQL?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` require a `ON` clause. Maybe you meant `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: @GMB I meant to add the ON clause after I got the first part of the syntax right, but cross join does work, so it appears that I simply need to add the on clause.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the ON clause, as you figured it out yourself:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(VALUES (1), (3), (5), (7), (9) ) AS X(a)
full outer JOIN 
(VALUES (0), (2), (4), (6), (8) ) AS Y(b)
on X.a=Y.b;
```